# Batch remove part of string after “-1” is found or any other number “-[0-9]”

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I got a file containing a string on each line like this:

```
fruit-apple-1.5.6
vegtable-sla-mc5-6.5-16515
extra-huh-9.5-511-515
extra-3.2
```

I am iterating over it and want it to remove the part of the string on the right after in find "-" + any number "-0","-1","-2","-9",...

so output should be

```
fruit-apple
vegtable-sla-mc5
extra-huh
extra
```

this is code i have but it only works with a "-" i cant combine it so it takes "-" + any number like "-1","-5","-2",...

```
for /f "delims=|" %%A in ("!fileNameCheck:-=|!") do (
echo stripped string = %%A
)
```

complete code not necessary i think but in case u need it below

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set "RawPath=%~dp0"


FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=*" %%M IN ("%RawPath%/mods") DO (
REM for %%f in (*.jar) do (
    Set "fileNameCheck=%%M"
    for /f "delims=|" %%A in ("!fileNameCheck:-=|!") do (
        Echo [46m%%A[0m
        if exist "%~dp0%%A*.jar" (
            REM echo [32mFound %%A "%~dp0%%A*.jar"[0m
            if exist "%~dp0%%M" (
                REM echo [42mUp to Date[0m [32m%%A "%~dp0%%M"[0m
            ) else (
                for %%j in (*.jar) do (
                    echo %%j |find "%%A" >nul
                    if not errorlevel 1 (
                        echo [41mDifferent Version[0m [31m%%j [0m[90mNewer version[0m [32m%%M[0m 
                    )
                    
                )
                
            )
        ) else (
            REM echo [31mMissing %%A[0m
        )
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: So you want to remove the version and the last dash?

Comment: if its has a dash and any number yes so remove -9.15.5 not -forge

Comment: Are there any numerals in the part to be kept?

Comment: In your examples, the all strings to be removed occur after the final dash. Is this always true of the actual data to be manipulated?

Comment: @T3RR0R no, that is not the case as per the first comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the strings do not contain any of the caracters `?`, `*`, `<` and `>`, the following script should do the trick:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."
set "_FILE=mods.txt"

rem // Read file line by line:
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
    rem // Store current line, initialise variables:
    set "LINE=%%L" & set "PREV=-" & set "COLL=-"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Split line string at every `-` and iterate through items;
    rem    (`?`, `*`, `<`, `>` must not occur in the string!): */
    for %%I in ("!LINE:-=" "!") do (
        endlocal & set "ITEM=%%~I"
        rem // Check whether item only consists of numerals and `.`:
        (
            rem // This loop executes when there are other characters:
            for /F "delims=0123456789. eol=." %%J in ("%%~I") do (
                setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                rem /* Rebuilt string with currently found items; if there
                rem    are other items following numeric ones, keep them: */
                for /F "delims=" %%K in ("!COLL!!PREV:~1!-!ITEM!") do (
                    endlocal & set "COLL=%%K" & set "PREV=-"
                )
            )
        ) || (
            rem // This section runs when there are numerals and `.`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            for /F "delims=" %%K in ("!PREV!-!ITEM!") do (
                rem /* Store numeric items in a separate buffer; if there
                rem    are no other items following, this is dismissed: */
                endlocal & set "PREV=%%K"
            )
        )
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem // Return rebuilt line string:
    echo(!COLL:~2!
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The example input file `mods.txt`:

> ```cmd
> fruit-apple-1.5.6
> vegtable-sla-mc5-6.5
> extra-huh-9.5
> extra-3.2
> test-9.15.5
> keep-forge
> name-subname-10.5-55.5
> globalxp-1.16.5
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more-3.4
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more-3.4-5.6-7
> 8.9
> 1.2.3-lead
> 1.2.3-4.5.6-7.8.9-lead-mult
> ```

leads to the following output:

> ```cmd
> fruit-apple
> vegtable-sla-mc5
> extra-huh
> extra
> test
> keep-forge
> name-subname
> globalxp
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more
> mix-1.2-string-10.5-55.5-more
>
> 1.2.3-lead
> 1.2.3-4.5.6-7.8.9-lead-mult
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to replace the `-` with `\` and then use variable substitution to strip the `%%~ni` part from the string. We just need to remove the first and last occurrence then from the string. `findstr` will determine that the end of string needs to be `-num.*`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.jar ^| findstr /RC:"-[0-9].*$"') do (
        set "line=%%~nxA"
        for %%i in ("!line:-=\!") do set "final=%%~pi"
        set "final=!final:~0,-1!-"
        echo !final! | findstr /RC:"\\[0-9].*$" >nul 2>&1
        if !errorlevel! equ 0 (
            for %%s in ("!final!") do set "final=%%~ps"
            set final=!final!
        )
        set "final=!final:~0,-1!"
        set "final=!final:~1!"
        echo !final:\=-!
)
```

the edited code should take care of the additional `-` as per your comment example `name-subname-10.5-55.5`

Comment: Users-green-Desktop-space folder-mods-globalxp-1.16.5
is the result it should be globalxp
and the path also changed from Users/green/Desktop/space folder/mods/
thx for the help but doesn't work

since it starts from the right it only removes the first - and number it encounters from the right but if there more on the left it doesnt like this 
name-subname-10.5-55.5 will only remove -55.5 instead of -10.5-55.5

Comment: as for your last statement in the comment, you did not give an example of that in your original question so I did not consider that.

Comment: unfortunate same result ```extraboats-1.16.5-2.1.0.jar``` will output ```Users-green-Desktop-space folder-mods-extraboats-1.16.5``` instead of ```extraboats```
i am playing around with ur code but seems to not do it its in the right direction i think tho

i am sorry to be such a pain in the cheecks its hard to explain it for me

Comment: it is not possible. I am setting the name to be the name and extension only, it cannot take in the path of the file, you must have changed something in my code and not used it as I posted it.

Comment: i runned ur code again a sec ago it return the path + filename not the file name itself

Comment: Did you copy the code as is after I edited it and ran it ons its own?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an untested idea, which may not be particularly quick, especially if you have a large number of strings in your `mods` file:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For /F %%G In ('Echo Prompt $E ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D'
) Do Set "$E=%%G"
For /F Delims^=^ EOL^=^ UseBackQ %%G In ("%~dp0mods") Do (Set "Line=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    For /L %%H In (0 1 9) Do For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%I In (
        '(Echo(^) ^| Set /P "=!Line:-%%H="^&:"!" 0^<NUL') Do Set "Line=%%I" 
    Echo(%$E%[46m!Line!%$E%[0m
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```